# android webview after certain activity clear history

Tags: android, webview

i'm doing webview android. 
what I want to do is.
after certain activity.

I want to prevent the 'back' button.
it means clear the webview history or others.

which one should I clear to prevent to go back after certain activitry

Answer (score 0):

Visible and enable back button action if the *WebView* in not Visible try the below code in your Activity

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            // dont pass back button action
            if(webview.canGoBack()){
                webview.goBack();
            }
            return;
        }else{
            // pass back button action
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to make back button enable  in every situation. <br/> but when I submit the some picture to the server. I want to refresh all the caches to make sure user does not go back to the save page again. is it possible? in webview?